# Unable to locate element error using selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

i m trying to get the element using selenium by id and by XPATH but in both cases unable to locate error occurs.
Code:

```
IWebDriver dr = new ChromeDriver();
 dr.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://epaper.dawn.com/");
 IWebElement today = dr.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='planetmap']"));
```

Code of the element is

I have tried both id and XPATH method

Comment: what is the error your are getting?

Comment: have you tried dr.FindElement(By.Id("planetmap"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is inside an `iframe`, *switch to it first*:

```
dr.SwitchTo().Frame("DawnPaperFrame");
IWebElement today = dr.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='planetmap']"));
```

Comment: Also wait until the element is visible, because it may take time for the element to appear after the page is loaded (If for example the site is using angular)